# JInternal Frame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

my entire program has been developed in java language using TextPad editor. i wanted to open frames inside mainframe but there is no response through the toolbar button or menu item that are selected. although there is no error during compile time or run time. the internalframe does not open at all

for example :

```
public class Xyz extends JInternalFrame
{
    public Xyz()
    {
         super("Java", true, true, true, true);
         //here are initialization and database connection part.

    }
 }
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: please show also the code where you use this class. also, have you read this already? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Comment: Make sure you read through [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) and understand how `JInternalFrame`s work.  Also, `JInternalFrame`'s are invisible by default (and have no size or location either)